# Дерективы section и sections в openMP c++

Tags: c++, openmp

Решаю следующую задачу:

> Изучите OpenMP-директивы создания параллельных секций sections и
> section. Напишите программу, содержащую 3 параллельные секции, внутри
> каждой из которых должно выводиться сообщение:
> [<Номер нити>]: came in section <Номер секции>
> Вне секций внутри параллельной области должно выводиться
> следующее сообщение:
> [<Номер нити>]: parallel region
> Запустите приложение на 2-х, 3-х, 4-х нитях. Проследите, как нити
> распределяются по параллельным секциям.
> Входные данные: k – количество нитей в параллельной области.
> Выходные данные: k-строк вида «[<Номер нити>]: came in section <Номер
> секции>», k-строк вида «[<Номер нити>]: parallel region».
> Пример входных и выходных данных

Входные данные:

- 3

Выходные данные:

- [0]: came in section 1
- [1]: came in section 2
- [2]: came in section 3
- [0]: parallel region
- [1]: parallel region
- [2]: parallel region

Я не совсем понимаю как правильно реализовать следующую часть задачи

> Вне секций внутри параллельной области должно выводиться следующее сообщение: [<Номер нити>]: parallel region

Пробовала вставлять вывод строки после 3х секций, но получаю ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где небходимо организовать вывод.
Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    omp_set_num_threads(k);
#pragma omp parallel sections
    {
#pragma omp section
        {
            cout << "[" << omp_get_thread_num() << "]: came in section 1" << endl;
        }
#pragma omp section
        {
            cout << "[" << omp_get_thread_num() << "]: came in section 2" << endl;
        }
#pragma omp section
        {
            cout << "[" << omp_get_thread_num() << "]: came in section 3" << endl;
        }
        //cout << "[" << omp_get_thread_num() << "]: parallel region";
    }
}
```

Comment: Как где? Уже за пределами `#pragma omp parallel sections` — после той фигурной скобки, перед которой эта строка сейчас находится...

Comment: Но тогда в выводе будет только одна строка: [0]: parallel region

Comment: Вывод  "parallel region" - дулжен быть внутри `#pragma omp parallel` но не внутри `#pragma omp parallel sections`.